# Push only the .gitignore file from the child and root directories

Tags: git

I have the following structure:

> public/
>
> - uploads/
>
>   - cover-photos/
>
>     - thumbnail/
>   - profile-photos/
>
>     - original/
>     - thumbnail/

I would like to push those directories without any content in the server, so I tried to accomplish that by adding an empty .gitkeep file in each of those directories and used the following code:

```
/public/uploads/cover-photos/thumbnail/*
!/public/uploads/cover-photos/thumbnail/.gitkeep
/public/uploads/profile-photos/original/*
!/public/uploads/profile-photos/original/.gitkeep
/public/uploads/profile-photos/thumbnail/*
!/public/uploads/profile-photos/thumbnail/.gitkeep
```

This works fine only for the child directories, thumbnail and original. If I add any file there, git will ignore those, but if I add a file in (for example) /public/uploads/cover-photos/ then git will track it and push it. How can i achieve what I want for the rest of the directories?

Comment: My preference is to use the `.gitignore` file as the reason that the directory gets created. That is, each "empty" directory contains one `.gitignore` file whose contents start with `*` and `!/.gitignore`. Add any sub-directories as `!/subdir/` to force them to be included as well, and start them off with the standard keep-this-directory `.gitignore` file with the two entries.

Comment: This particular pattern is clear and obvious and never requires any additional thought, and yet is also easy to update should certain files need to be un-ignored (so only minor additional thought is required at that point).

Answer (score 0):

You may do it with:

```
/public/uploads/*/**/*

!/public/uploads/cover-photos/thumbnail/
!/public/uploads/cover-photos/thumbnail/.gitkeep

!/public/uploads/profile-photos/original/
!/public/uploads/profile-photos/original/.gitkeep

!/public/uploads/profile-photos/thumbnail/
!/public/uploads/profile-photos/thumbnail/.gitkeep
```

The first line matches both `/public/uploads/cover-photos/*` and `/public/uploads/cover-photos/thumbnail/*` but not `/public/uploads/*` (you may use `/public/uploads/**/*` if you want files there included). However, it also ignores the sub-directories including the `.gitkeep`s ([documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)):

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.

So you will need to first re-include the directory and then the `.gitkeep`s.

```
!/public/uploads/profile-photos/thumbnail/
!/public/uploads/profile-photos/thumbnail/.gitkeep
```

Comment: That didn't work. If I add a file in the directory /public/uploads/cover-photos/ for example, git will detect the file there when I do not want it to.

Comment: @zeeks I've set up an example project [here](https://github.com/gudzpoz/gitignore-example) and it works fine for me. Would you please check [if the file has already been tracked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/) or give a more detailed example?